# How do I flush a file in D?

Tags: file-io, d

In D, I'm writing to a file:

```
File opfile = File(opdir~opname, "w");
... //first gap
opfile.writeln("somestuff");
... //second gap
opfile.writeln("otherstuff");
```

In this case, the stuff in the first gap takes several minutes to run, and the stuff in the second gap takes several hours, and I'd like to see "somestuff" written to the file before the end of the program as a sanity check.

It looks to me like D is using buffered output, and consequently, all the output is written at once after second gap. In C++ I'd use ostream::flush to manually flush opfile prior to the second gap.

What is the equivalent operation in D? I cannot find it in the documentation for std.file.

Comment: Did you try `opfile.flush()`?

Comment: [std.stdio](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_stdio.html) -- Ctrl-F "flush" and you should see it.

Comment: I get that this turned out to be what you'd expect, but I don't understand the downvotes. This is real question, it's not currently on SE, and the answer is not in the documentation for std.file, which (at least for me), was the first place to check.

Comment: @JohnDoucette people tend to down vote googleble questions, or things that a simple ctrl+F in the documentation will fix

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [`opfile.flush()`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_stdio.html#.File.flush)

> Calls fflush for the file handle.

Comment: Nope. I was looking in the documentation for std.file (http://dlang.org/phobos/std_file), rather than std.stdio. Figures that it's the first thing you'd expect. (I'll accept once the 10 minute restriction expires)